# Calculate pan vs swipe amount

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a Tableview of weeks for showing the weather each week. In this tableview, you can swipe left to go to detailed view of the week, or right to go out of the tableview and to a main menu. But there is 52 weeks i can also scroll through in the tableview and I am trying to make it feel when you are swiping vs panning, as it is of now, you have to be very precise when swiping to the sides. And the problem with this is that often i wanna swipe into detailed view, the app things i wanna swipe a small amout of up or down in stead.

I tried with:

```
 // MARK: Gesture settings

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Is there a way to make the swiping easier to trigger? For example if im tryin got swipe from side to side and if its not in a 0 or 180 degree angle but -10/10 or 170/160, i still want it to be considered a swipe!

Thanks guys, have a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about putting your `UITableView` inside a `UICollectionView` instead? It sounds like it might be more appropriate as you'd have 52 collection view cells and be able to reuse the tableview based on the index path of those items.

Comment: I have not. Ill read more of it but in the intro Apple says "Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts. ". And i dont really need more customizable. I just click on a row and then it goes to another view to fetch and present that weeks data! How is collectionviews more appropriate?

Comment: You can page and scroll horizontally or vertically.. with reuse.. which is what I understood you needed? `pagingEnabled`